# Why callbacks function are not fired?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, gps, location, gis

I have this function that indicates if geolocation is enabled on the broweser:

```js
function geolocationInfo() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }
    else {
        return "Geolocation not works in this browser";
    }
}

  function success(position) {
        var crd = position.coords;

        console.log('Ваше текущее метоположение:');
        console.log(`Широта: ${crd.latitude}`);
        console.log(`Долгота: ${crd.longitude}`);
        console.log(`Плюс-минус ${crd.accuracy} метров.`);
    }

    function error(error) {
        switch (error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                return "Geolocation disabled";
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                return "GeoLocation is not available";
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                return "Time is ends";
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                return "error.";               
        }
    }
```

The problem is callback functions are not fired.

Any idea why callbacks(success and errors) are not fired?

Comment: usually the browser will ask the user to allow/deny geolocation - neither callback is called until one of those choices is made or remembered for this site - so, no other errors in the console at all? Which browser, by the way? and is the page https or http?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you try to use your code inside the chrome's console, and you run your function

```
geolocationInfo()
```

Then check the pop-up window with permissions in your browser, as the user has to allow the web-page to see the location

[image: Example in Chrome]

Comment: Vitaliy thanks, I just try to configure why my code doesn't works

Comment: Michael, your code works fine for me (Chrome 83.0.4103.61), as soon as you click "allow" or "block" you will see the callback results.